# Drop ALL Views in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to drop all the views in my SQLite database. Please help.

I am aware I can drop views if I know the view name...

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_name
```

... but I'd like to drop views that exist but for which I don't know the name.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the views by querying the sqlite_master table (a system table).

e.g.

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'view';
```

The **name** column will be the name of the view.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'view';` is helpful thank you. I have upvoted, however this only provides half an answer so I cannot accept.  How do I send the result of this command into multiple `DROP VIEW` commands?

Comment: @OliverPearmain you would have to do that programatically as you cannot generate and execute drop commands via a query. You could generate the SQL e.g. SELECT 'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS '||name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'view'; but you need to loop through the resultset to execute the SQL.